# Will my African Dwarf Frog die?

Tags: frogs

I have an African Dwarf frog in my fish tank right now, and an accident happened where I walked up too fast to the tank and scared her. She managed to jump out of a small hole in the top meant for the filter wires onto the floor. I was luckily able to catch her very quickly and get her back into the tank, but she did take a fall of a couple of feet (probably about two and a half feet). She looks relatively ok right now, but I’m just worried if there’s a chance that she might die. I know they’re very fragile, if someone can help me out please let me know!

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please take the [tour] and have a look at the [help]. The problem with this kind of question is that we don't know any more than you do and we cannot help you with medical emergencies. If you notice a severe change in behavior or have a medical emergency, a local vet is the best help you can get. In such situations, please don't wait for answers from strangers on the internet, contact you local vet and get help as soon as possible.